# AngularJS add CSS class on new item in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Here is my view for a list.

```
<a href="#/">back...</a>
<ul>
    <input type="text" ng-model="search">

    <li ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search | orderBy:'date'">
        {{ item.ID }} - {{ item.heading }} - {{ item.date | date:"dd.MM.yy" }}
        <button ng-click="deleteItem(item.ID)">del</button>
    </li>

    <form>
        <input type="text" ng-model="itemName">
        <input type="date" min="{{ date }}" max="{{ maxDate }}" value="{{ date }}" ng-model="itemDate">
        <button ng-click="addItem()">add</button>
    </form>
</ul>
```

On click my contoller adds a new item to the view, which works fine. Now i want to animate only the new item with css3. Therefore the new item needs a class. How can i achieve this with angular?

Comment: If it is a last member in an array so give a special class may be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use a function to add an Item, you could also set a variable to know which Id is the last inserted while adding the item to the list

First, you can see what I did here http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/Eb2kR/
I just created a `lastInsertedId` variable, which I use to add a class in the ng-repeat :

```
<span ng-class='{lastinserted: item.ID==lastInsertedId}'>{{ item.ID }} - {{ item.heading }} - {{ item.date | date:"dd.MM.yy" }}</span>
```

I had no idea how you implemented you addItem method and what are your IDs, so I created my own method and I assumed your IDs are unique numbers, but it could work with anything (hoping you can find a unique set of data)

```
$scope.addItem=function(){
        var dd=new Date($scope.itemDate);       
        $scope.items.push( {"ID":$scope.items.length+1, "heading":$scope.itemName, "date":dd.getTime()});
        $scope.lastInsertedId=$scope.items.length;
        }
```

I change the last inserted id, which will apply the selected class  to the item
You could also unset the `lastInsertedId` value in the `delItem()` method

If you have a more difficult logic (here I assumed you had unique IDs) you can also use a function in the `ng-class`. Here, on my example it wouldn't be [hard to code](http://jsfiddle.net/DotDotDot/Eb2kR/2/) :

```
$scope.amITheOne=function(item){
    return item.ID==$scope.lastInsertedId;
}
```

then

```
<span ng-class='{lastinserted: amITheOne(item)}'>
```

It doesn't change much with a simple logic, but you could totally have a logic based on the ID, the name and the date for example

Have fun

Answer (score 3):

This should assign class `the-class` to the last element of the list dynamically:

```
<li ng-class="{'the-class': $last}" ng-repeat="item in items | filter:search | orderBy:'date'">
    {{ item.ID }} - {{ item.heading }} - {{ item.date | date:"dd.MM.yy" }}
    <button ng-click="deleteItem(item.ID)">del</button>
</li>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using Angular 1.1.5, you can use ngAnimate enter event instead which is precisely designed for this kind of situation.

Have a look at http://www.nganimate.org/ and http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive:ngAnimate